# Convert Access delete distinctrow (multi table delete) to TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I have this query ... I need to change this to a TSQL supported statement ... I believe I need to change to where not exists ... but do I also need 3 delete statments (a delete for each table?)

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW TABLE1.*, TABLE2.column1, TABLE3.column2
FROM (
  TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON (TABLE1.column3 = TABLE2.column3)
    AND (TABLE1.column1 = TABLE2.column1)
  )
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON (TABLE1.column3 = TABLE3.column3)
  AND (TABLE1.column1 = TABLE3.column2)
WHERE (
    ((TABLE2.column1) IS NULL)
    AND ((TABLE3.column2) IS NULL)
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly , you can do this by getting the key values for each table with a select.  Then use 3 delete statements

```
DECLARE @RecIds AS TABLE (sTableName VARCHAR(100), recidTableXRecord INT)

INSERT INTO @RecIds (recidTable1 , recidTableXRecord)
SELECT 'Table1', <Unique Record Id for table 1>
FROM  .... ( ) AS TableRecords1

INSERT INTO @RecIds (recidTable2 , recidTableXRecord)
SELECT 'Table2', <Unique Record Id for table 1>
FROM  .... ( ) AS TableRecords1

INSERT INTO @RecIds (recidTable3 , recidTableXRecord)
SELECT 'Table3', <Unique Record Id for table 1>
FROM  .... ( ) AS TableRecords1
```

... then delete

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE recidTable1 IN (SELECT recidTableXRecord FROM @RecIds WHERE sTableName ='TABLE1')

DELETE FROM TABLE2 WHERE recidTable1 IN (SELECT recidTableXRecord FROM @RecIds WHERE sTableName ='TABLE2')

DELETE FROM TABLE3 WHERE recidTable1 IN (SELECT recidTableXRecord FROM @RecIds WHERE sTableName ='TABLE3')
```

... There may be better ways but this will work and is easy to maintain.
Recommend putting all in a transaction.